# Corrupt DLL "Netutils.dll"

Tags: windows-7, windows, dll, filesystem-corruption

I have never encountered this particular error before so any help will be fantastic. I had a computer reported to me that wouldn't allow the user to log in, then the user reported that they couldn't run most programs. The error message they received is shown in the image below:

[image: Error Message Shown Here]

I have tried to replace the file with a new version of the DLL file. The system would not allow it to be pasted over.

I tried to restore the pc to May, but because of the corrupted file system restore said it can not restore the drive with errors present.

I tried to recover the pc through using a backup image however the windows backup and restore option will not load. By not load you can click on the link or try and execute it from command line it will not open.

All these options have also been attempted in safe mode with no success.

I'm now out of ideas. I'm doing all this via remote access as the machine is 200+ miles away to physically look at it.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: run **sfc /scannow** to fix DLL issues: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: Thank you i will run this as soon as i can get hold of the user and see if it works.

Comment: Magicandre1981 Can you add your solution and i'll mark it as the answer and up vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix Windows DLL issues (missing or corrupted files) in Windows XP till 7, run [sfc /scannow](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) from a command prompt (cmd.exe) [which is started as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token).

Answer (score 0):

The `sfc /scannow` option did not work for me.

I had to use the Startup Repair tool as explained [here](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/fix-windows-7-using-startup-repair).